# Angular Routeprovider: send simple POST request

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm working on a little Angular example project, using something like this

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            templateUrl: 'view1',
            controller: 'Ctrl1'
        })
        .when('/view1', {
            templateUrl: 'view2',
            controller: 'Ctrl2'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1'});
});
```

Now I would like to add a button sending a simple GET "/setDatabaseFlag". No template loading, no new controller. I realized that every call to localhost (my base url for the test) runs through the routeProvider. So I tried to find something like

```
        .when('/setDatabaseFlag', {
             $http.get('/setDatabaseFlag');
        })
```

I found an example using

```
        .when('/setDatabaseFlag', {
            action: doSomething
        })
```

but $http is not available here. Also "action" seems undocumented.

I guess there must be another approach. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: This is what controllers are for. `controller: function($http) { ... }`

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for might be resolve. Look into that. There are many ways you can do this.

Comment: Ok, a controller function is probably an easy way. Let me try this. Thanks!

Comment: Hm .. very simple with $scope.setDbFlag = function(sFlag) {...}, thanks again.